# A corollary of Li-Yau-Hamilton estimate

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

Picture below is from the Hamilton's [The Harnack estimate for the Ricci flow](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214453430) .How to get the corollary 1.2 by Theorem 1.1 ? It seemly be not immediately and hard to compute. Maybe  just because I am rookie.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace of $M_{ij} W_i W_j$ over $W_i$ (in an orthonormal frame) is $$\frac 1 2 \left( \Delta R + 2 R_{kl}R_{kl} + \frac R t\right).$$

With the given $U$, $2P_{ijk} U_{ij} W_k$ is

$$ (D_i R_{jk} - D_j R_{ik})(V_i W_j W_k - V_j W_i W_k);$$

so tracing over $W$ and applying the twice-contracted second Bianchi identity $\rm{div Rc}  = \frac12 \nabla \rm Scal$ we get

$$ V_i D_i R - V_i D_j R_{ij} - V_j D_i R_{ji} + V_j D_j R = 2\left(V_iD_iR-V_jD_jR_{ij}\right) = 2\left( V_i D_i R - \frac 1 2 V_j D_j R \right) = V_i D_i R.$$

Finally

$$R_{ijkl} U_{ij}U_{kl} = \frac14 R_{ijkl} (V_i W_j - W_i V_j)(V_k W_l - W_k V_l)$$

has trace $R_{ik} V_i V_k$ (all four terms in the expansion are the same due to the Riemann tensor symmetries), so putting this all together the conclusion of the theorem in this case is

$$\Delta R + 2 R_{kl} R_{kl} + \frac R t + 2V_i D_i R + 2 R_{ik}V_iV_k \ge 0.$$

Since $\partial_t R = \Delta R + 2 R_{ik} R_{ik}$ under Ricci flow, this is exactly the Corollary.

Comment: How to trace of $\nabla_i\nabla_j R W_i W_j$ over $W_i$ ?

Comment: @lanse7pty: it's just $\sum_{i} \nabla_{W_i} \nabla_{W_i} R$ for $W_i$ an orthonormal basis, so it's the trace of the Hessian; i.e. the Laplacian.